# scrolling the silverlight ScrollViewer programmatically

Tags: silverlight

i have a silverlight scrollviewer in my xaml page as below

```
 <ScrollViewer x:Name="scroller" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Height="140" BorderBrush="{x:Null}">

contents here

</ScrollViewer >
```

and i am trying to move the scroll bar programmatically  as below but it didnt worked out

```
  scroller.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(250);
scroller.lineleft();
scroller.moveleft();
                this.UpdateLayout();
                Upperscroller.UpdateLayout();
```

can any body guide me how to move the scrollbar programmatically

Comment: Do you have contents in the Scrollviewer that is at leasr 250 pixels wider than the actual width of the Scrollviewer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a test, this code hooked up to button moves the scrollbar with nothing else required:

```
scroller.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(scroller.HorizontalOffset + 10);
```

The content was very wide though. AnthonyWJones is correct in his comment. The content must be at least 250 **+ the width of your scrollviewer** to have any effect.  HorizontalOffset is the offset of the left side of the scrollview content.

Try smaller values when testing :)

Comment: Also while debugging i saw the width of thescroller is NaN?does it have something to do?

Comment: You will get Nan on some size properties if you access them before the control has been sized & rendered the first time. If you have to access those properties before they may be set, check the values with if (!Double.IsNan(*value*)) etc

Comment: as u said i checked "The content must be at least 250 + the width of your scrollviewer to have any effect." but still the problem persists.

Comment: @subash: You will have to provide more Xaml/code for anyone to reproduce and fix the problem. Thanks.